# docker logs "--until" option not working anymore after docker restart

Tags: docker, logging, containers

I had a problem with a docker container which I needed to do a `docker restart <container_name>` command.
This worked all as expected and when I used `docker logs -f <container_name>` it showed me the successful container restart message followed by new logs again.

After that I wanted to see old logs for detecting the problem of the service that runs inside the container, so I did `docker logs --unti=30m <container_name>` which worked as expected and I could go through the logs at that time. But after some digging I wanted to execute the same logs command, but it returned nothing anymore.

So I tried to find out how far I can go back in time, and it may be related to the docker restart, since I can only go back in time until roughly that point when I restarted the container + 10 mins (so I restarted at 9:45 and could only query back until 9:55). I'm also not sure if the logs are still there or not. The `--since` option also doesn't go back further than 9:55.

Did anyone else have this problem? Is there a fix for this or maybe a bug in docker logs? AFAIK logs should persist as long as I don't do `docker rm <container_name>` right?

Thank you so much!